# Use Devise to prevent user set as 'false' (deactivated) on database from login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization

My Rails application uses Devise for authorization and sometimes the user that is trying to log in is disabled on database with a flag set as 'false'.

Is there a way Devise use this flag to prevent deactivated users from log in the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add checking your `deactivated` field to `active_for_authentication?` method like this:

```
def active_for_authentication? 
  super && !deactivated? 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! And just in case someone is trying to realize where to put the code: in the 'user' model.